# Should users improve a question based on comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, review, edits

Say, the OP made some clarifications about their question later in a comment. And for some reason, the OP decides not to include the clarification as an edit in their question. Another user comes up, takes that comment, and includes it in the question as an edit.

Now, this could be a logical addition to the question that might look spam-y during an edit review (if the editor hasn't explicitly mentioned that this was discussed below).

So my question is,

1. Should other users improve a question that's not theirs, based on a comment that's not theirs either?
2. What can be done if their edit, while logical, is rejected during review?

Answer (score 14):

You should improve a question based on an OP comment, but you should also make it clear in the description of your edit that that's what you're doing.

As Kate Gregory says

> edit reviewers can't see the comments. So it's vital that your edit summary explains what you are doing and why. Otherwise reviewers will reject because you're just adding sentences out of the blue.

If your edit is rejected you can comment on the question or possibly raise it on your site Meta. Some higher rep user may go and make the edit for you if you do that.

Comment: edit reviewers can't see the comments. So it's vital that your edit summary explains what you are doing and why. Otherwise reviewers will reject because you're just adding sentences out of the blue.

Answer (score 11):

The aim is to continuously improve all questions and all answers.

Consequently, if an editor is confident that making an edit based on a comment that is not theirs ***will improve a post*** that is not theirs, then they should be encouraged to do so.

Editors should be aware that, as [commented by @KateGregory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289890/should-users-improve-a-question-based-on-comments/289891#comment941308_289892) on another answer:

> edit reviewers can't see the comments. So it's vital that your edit
>   summary explains what you are doing and why. Otherwise reviewers will
>   reject because you're just adding sentences out of the blue.

If such an edit is rejected during review then I think the editor should make their case as a comment on the post querying why the edit was not approved.